# Cant Drag and Drop Activities for Pipeline

Tags: azure-data-factory

Hi I am new to Azure Data Factory, I was hoping to play around and create a pipeline to see how it works. I have a free trial setup with all linked services and connections. I am having trouble as I try to drag and drop any activities, I cant seem to to drag any activities. please let me know

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: @TrevorBrooks I am using Chrome

Comment: This sounds very weird.  I've been using ADF for the past 6 months and I've never seen any activity like you described.  Can you clear your browser's cache and re-try?

Comment: @asher ya I cleared the cache and rebooted my system, that worked

Comment: Niiiicccceeee!!!!!

Comment: @rakshithsai i tried to summary the solution as answer. if you don't mind, you could accept it to end this case which is beneficial for others'  on the forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Question: I am having trouble as I try to drag and drop any
>   activities, I cant seem to to  drag any activities.

Just for summary, actually it may be caused by the system or browser cache. The solution is clearing the cache and reboot system.

Comment: For any unfortunate soul stumbling on this, try restarting chrome before clearing your cache.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in both Edge and Chrome.  Clearing the browser cache and restarting the system did not work for me.

I was able to fix the problem by navigating to the browser Settings menu and then performing Reset Settings / Restore settings to their default values.